# How to kill previous HttpRequest for a user session in a HttpServlet

Tags: java, servlets

Is there any way to locate a previous HttpRequest, for a given session?

Web client sends request to a long running web service.  While this service is running the client sends another request. I want to locate the first request and send it a stop signal.

Background:
I have a web service that requires 2-4 seconds to process.  The servlet is hosted in a Tomcat container and is using OSGi to access the main processor in another plugin.

The requests come from another web site that allows users to make 10 or so requests at a time.  While the user is waiting they may make another page change that will start another 10 web requests.   I need a way to locate the previous requests.  Then I'll find a way to send a stop signal to the long running process which will allow the original HttpRequest to finish with some suitable error code.

Perhaps another way to look at this problem is to say:  if a client makes a series of requests that overlap then we only want to service the last request and cancel the previous requests as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you to the people who have answered. Sorry, I may not have a chance to verify your answers for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `HttpSession` gives you what you are looking for, but I would recommend making some kind of object that your requests can periodically check to see if they are the "newest" request.  If they are no longer the newest request then they can stop themselves and return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the previous request job task in the session. And on next parallel request, you can get the earlier request job and take the action you want.